# Sequence of Verbs in Present Perfect

Tags: verbs, present-perfect

What is the meaning differences of sentences below? or is there any one that is incorrect?

1-I have said I was sick

2-I have said I am sick

3-I have said I have been sick

Comment: What are your theories and current understanding here? What has your previous research discovered? Questions that ask us to tell you everything to know about blah are too vague. We don't know where to start, and time and space are finite.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the following sentences is used in a tense.
The first one is in the past tense (I was sick at a period in the past)
The second sentence is in the present tense ( I am sick right now)
While the last sentence is in the present perfect which links the past with the present time (I am sick for a period of time in the past and it continues till now)

Comment: All of this is misleading for reported past speech. Consider *I have often said that I am sick to get out of going to school.* Backshifting to *I was sick* is an option, but not required. But retaining the present tense *am* does not mean that I am sick right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'saying' is over. You said about different occasions.

> 1- You were absent yesterday. Why?  Today You have said you were sick
>   (yesterday)
>
> 2- Today you are not attending the class. Why? You are sick. Have you
>   informed the teacher? Yes, I have said I am sick.
>
> 3- You were absent for some days and today also you are going to be
>   absent. Why? Have you informed the teacher? Yes, I have said that I
>   have been sick and I have not yet recovered.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Now I am just wondering if 2&3 can be interchangeable ?

Comment: They are different in meaning. Present Perfect means you are sick from some time in the past and still continuing in that state in the present time. The simple present doesn't have that meaning; it means you are sick at present. Also note simple present tense is an all-inclusive time tense to refer to something in a permanent state, as in: I am a doctor = (yesterday, today and tomorrow) 'I am a doctor'.